# Select columns with same name after join

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Basically I need to do this query using `Zend_Db_Select`:

```sql
SELECT *, `matches`.`name` AS superName, `dimension`.`name` AS someName 
FROM `matches`
JOIN `dimension` ON [whatever condition]
-- etc, etc.
```

Doing joins and the rest is easy eventually going to something like:

```
$select = Globals::db()->select();
$select -> from("matches")
        -> join("dimension", "`matches`.`idDimension` = `dimension`.`idDimension`")
        -> join("accounts", "`accounts`.idAccount = `matches`.idOwner");        
     // -> etc, etc

return Globals::db()->fetchAll($select);
```

The problem is that the column `name` appears in more than 1 table so `name` by itself is ambiguous therefore in response is `null`. How do I fix that?

I've tried:

```
$select = Globals::db()->select();
$select -> from("matches", "*, `matches`.`name`")
```

and

```
$select = Globals::db()->select();
$select -> from("matches", "*", "`matches`.`name`")
```

but both return error (column * not found and syntax error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$select -> from("matches", array("*", "name as superName"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify a correlation name (alias) `matches.*`

Comment: tried... not working. I can always switch to normal queries but would be lame.